# Removing text after a pattern and before a semicolon with gsub

Tags: r, gsub

In the following example, I want to remove everything after FAPESP and CNPq and keep everything else:

`"105 Group Science; Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo, FAPESP, (2015/07311-7, 2018/03211-6); Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior, CAPES; Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico, CNPq, (407543/2018-0, 420699/2018-0); Fundação Araucária; Ministry of Science and Technology, Taiwan, MOST"`

I need the following result:

`"105 Group Science; Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo, FAPESP; Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior, CAPES; Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico, CNPq; Fundação Araucária; Ministry of Science and Technology, Taiwan, MOST"`

Since I am working with a large data frame, I cannot use a simple function (for example,

```r
df$Funding <- gsub(", (2015/07311-7, 2018/03211-6) ", "", df$Funding)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: simpler still,

```r
gsub("(FAPESP|CNPq)[^;]*;", "\\1;", have)
# [1] "105 Group Science; Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo, FAPESP; Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior, CAPES; Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico, CNPq; Fundação Araucária; Ministry of Science and Technology, Taiwan, MOST"
gsub("(FAPESP|CNPq)[^;]*;", "\\1;", have) == want
# [1] TRUE
```

- `(FAPESP|CNPq)` match either substring and capture it
- `[^;]*` match 0 or more non-`;` characters, do not capture them
- `;` literal semicolon
- `\\1;` replace all of the previous match with the substring and a literal semicolon
- since we're using `gsub`, repeat that for the rest of the string

---

Another approach, since this data is `;`-delimited, is to split into sub-components, remove after each keyword (with less discrimination), and then re-collapse them around `;`. This is far less efficient than the above, but the method might be necessary or at least simplifying if/when the pattern is less clear. Use the above unless a simple regex doesn't work as well.

```r
out <- sapply(strsplit(have, ";"), function(s) paste(sub("(FAPESP|CNPq).*", "\\1", s), collapse = ";"))
out
# [1] "105 Group Science; Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo, FAPESP; Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior, CAPES; Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico, CNPq; Fundação Araucária; Ministry of Science and Technology, Taiwan, MOST"
identical(out, want)
# [1] TRUE
```

- `strsplit(., ";")` splits a string by the presence of semi-colons; it returns a list (the same length as the length of the string vector), each element of which may be 0+ length string vectors;
- we use `sapply` to iterate over each of the vector-elements in the list, applying the `sub` substring replacement
- `(FAPESP|CNPq)` matches (and preserves) either of the strings
- `.*` matches anything (including nothing), it is not collected
- together, `"(FAPESP|CNPq).*"` matches the substring and everything after it (per `;`-delimited string) and replaces it with the substring (via `"\\1"`)
- `paste(., collapse = ";")` restores the string as a `;`-delimited string

I think this means the code you need to fix `df$Funding` is

```r
df$Funding <-
  sapply(strsplit(df$Funding, ";"),
         function(s) paste(sub("(FAPESP|CNPq).*", "\\1", s), collapse = ";"))
```

We could have used `gsub` as well, but the specifics of *this* pattern did not require its `g`lobal nature.

---

Data

```r
have <- "105 Group Science; Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo, FAPESP, (2015/07311-7, 2018/03211-6); Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior, CAPES; Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico, CNPq, (407543/2018-0, 420699/2018-0); Fundação Araucária; Ministry of Science and Technology, Taiwan, MOST"
want <- "105 Group Science; Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo, FAPESP; Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior, CAPES; Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico, CNPq; Fundação Araucária; Ministry of Science and Technology, Taiwan, MOST"
```

Comment: @AriAlex, be sure to see my edit, a much faster (duh, should have tried that one first) expression.